# How to use a value from state to in other files

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I want to pass a value "hash" that i have stored in my state in a component file. I want that state value "hash" to use in sagas file as a parameter to a url. How can i do this. Below are mo code file.

**sagas file**

```
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { REQUEST_DATA } from './constants';
import { requestDataSuccess, requestDataFailed } from './actions';
import { fetchTxs } from './api';

export function fetchDataFromServer() {
```

> ```
>     return fetch('https://blockchain.info/rawtx/${hash}')
> ```

```
        .then((response) => response.json());
}

function* fetchData() {
    try {
        const data = yield call(fetchDataFromServer);
        yield put(requestDataSuccess(data));
    } catch (e) {
        yield put(requestDataFailed(e.message));
    }
}

// Individual exports for testing
export function* fetchSaga() {
    // See example in containers/HomePage/sagas.js
    yield takeLatest(REQUEST_DATA, fetchData)
}

// All sagas to be loaded
export default [
    fetchData,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` method. Here is an official doc https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#selectselector-args.

Example of using it

```
export const getSession = state => state.session;

// Saga
export function* saveChanges() {
  while(true) {
    yield take(SAVE_CHANGES);
    let session = yield select(getSession); // <-- get the session
    yield call(fetch, '/api/project', { body: session, method: 'PUT' });
    yield put({type: SAVE_SESSION_SUCCESS});
  }
}
```